# API Calls from external website to Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api, website-integration

I am building a web form so that user can enter their details in their which will eventually create a record in Salesforce. Is there any limitation or any precaution I should consider before implementing this approach? What is the best way to connect the web form and Salesforce - REST or SOAP? It is a simple form which gets the name , address and the course completed by the user.

I saw the API limits for Salesforce - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm

Is this some thing I should keep in mind? Is this limit imposed when a call is made to the Salesforce or from Salesforce?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes These limits will count you should consider that.

Now for the authentication into SF use `Partner WSDl` and do the authentication.

And for the data update you can use REST or SOAP in which you are more comfortable but if you are storing data in Custom objects then you can also use `Partner WSDl` to insert and update the data.